# Sorting through array c++

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

So I am attempting to do a bubble-like sort. Not a bubble sort because I don't want to exchange every single value that i run into. I simply want to find the smallest value of each index and place it in order. Such as in the arrayVal[3, 5, 2].

Instead of replacing the value 3 with 2 and then replacing 5 with 3. I want to find the smallest number of the entire array and place it at arrayVal[0] and then move to arrayVal[1].

I can't quite figure out how to do this and am kind of stuck.(I took out the <> on the libraries so you could see which libraries I am using)

```
#include iostream
#include cmath
#include ctime
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int STARTLOOP = 0;
    const int MAXLOOP = 5;
    const int MINRANGE = 1;
    const int MAXRANGE = 10;

    //int temp = 0;
    int smallestVal = 0;
    int arrayVal[MAXLOOP];

    srand(time(0));

    for (int i = STARTLOOP; i < MAXLOOP; i++)
    {
        arrayVal[i] = (rand() % MAXRANGE) + MINRANGE;
    }

    for (int i = STARTLOOP; i < MAXLOOP; i++)
    {
        cout << arrayVal[i] << endl;
    }

    cout << "Before the sort" << endl;

    for (int i = STARTLOOP; i < MAXLOOP; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i; j < MAXLOOP; j++)
        {
            if (arrayVal[j] < arrayVal[i])
            {
                arrayVal[i] = smallestVal;
            }

        }
    }

    for (int i = STARTLOOP; i < MAXLOOP; i++)
    {
        cout << arrayVal[i] << endl;
    }

    cout << "After the sort" << endl;

    return 0;
```

I also recognize I'm not using functions, i just wrote up the code because I was trying to figure this out. Thank you in advance.

Comment: So what was the question?

Comment: For what it's worth, what you're describing is normally called a "selection sort".

Comment: What *exactly* are you stuck on ?  What's going wrong, what's going right ?

Comment: What line are you stuck on?

Comment: Inside the nested loop. I'm attempting to do a selection sort I suppose, but did not know the name

Comment: Although I am not attempting to swap each and every value place. Only once the smallest value in the array is found for arrayVal[0] then arrayVal[1]... I want it to swap at the last possible moment

Comment: [Here is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24650626/how-to-implement-classic-sorting-algorithms-in-modern-c) a very good implementation of selection sort. If you are doing it as a learning exercise, try re-implementing other parts of `<algorithm>` in that style

Comment: `#include iostream` --> `#include <iostream>` and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're never setting `smallestVal` to anything from the array. You don't need nested loops. Just go through the array once, comparing each value to `smallestVal`. If it's smaller, you set `smallestVal` to that value. You should also have a variable that holds the index of the smallest value, which you update at the same time.

At the end, you swap the first element with the smallest one.

```
int smallestVal = arrayVal[STARTLOOP];
int smallestIndex = STARTLOOP;
for (int i = STARTLOOP + 1; i < MAXLOOP; i++) {
    if (arrayVal[i] < smallestVal) {
        smallestVal = arrayVal[i];
        smallestIndex = i;
    }
}
if (smallestIndex != STARTLOOP) { 
    // swap it with the first element
    int temp = arrayVal[STARTLOOP];
    arrayVal[STARTLOOP] = smallestVal;
    arrayVal[smallestIndex] = temp;
}
```

You can then increment `STARTLOOP` and repeat this.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to achieve is some sort of a modified insertion sort. Check out this implementation :

```
void sort(int values[], int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        int min = i;
        for ( int j = i ; j < n ; j++)
        {
            if (values[j]<values[min]) min =j;
        }
        while(values[min-1]>values[min])
        {
            if(min==0)
                break;
            if(values[min-1]!=values[min])
                swap (values+min-1,values+min);
            min--;

        }
    }
    return;
}
```

What this function does is that it searches the array every time for the smallest element starting from index `i` and when it finds this element it keeps on swapping it will all of the previous elements in the array until it reaches a smaller element.

Comment: Interesting, but should a void statement be returning anything? And thank you

Comment: No, it doesn't. We use `return;` to denote that we reached the end of the function.

Comment: There's no need for a `return;` statement at the end of the function.